# Why autowired object is null when the method using it is called from another class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

I'm doing a Spring Boot 2.1.6 project.

I have a class `ScheduledTasks` when I have an autowired object `db` which gives me access to `jdbcTemplate` so I can perform queries. When I call the `start` from main which is another file the `db` object is null. If I place the `start` method directly in main class `db` is not null.

I'm not sure what the issue is. I place `@Component` annotation in `ScheduledTasks` so that Spring is aware of my autowired object. What am I missing?

This is my `ScheduledTasks`:

```
@Component
public class ScheduledTasks {
    private Logger log = VastLogger.getLogger(TrackingEventController.class);

    @Autowired
    private DBHandler db;

    public void start() {
        if (db == null) {
            log.info("db is null from parent");
        }
    }
}
```

this is my main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
public class ServerMain implements CommandLineRunner {
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(ServerMain.class);

    @Autowired
    private DBHandler db;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.warn("from main");
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(ServerMain.class, args);

    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
        log.info("starting run");
        db.initDBTables();
        ScheduledTasks tasks = new ScheduledTasks();
        tasks.start();
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating `ScheduledTasks` using `new`. In that case, you are not using an object created by spring hence auto-wire will not work. You should also wire the `ScheduledTasks` object in the main class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
public class ServerMain implements CommandLineRunner {
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(ServerMain.class);

    @Autowired
    private DBHandler db;

    @Autowired
    private ScheduledTasks tasks;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.warn("from main");
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(ServerMain.class, args);

    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
        log.info("starting run");
        db.initDBTables();
        tasks.start();
    }
```